# Simple array of strings validation in Marshmallow

Tags: python, marshmallow

We have a series of API calls we are making that will require the passed data to be validated against Marshmallow-based (3.7.0) schemas before we make the API call. Most of the schema definitions are in the form:

```
class SomeSchema(Schema):
    Field1 = fields.Str(default='')
    Field2 = fields.Str(default='', missing='', allow_none=True)
    Field3 = fields.Int()
    etc
```

However we have one minor exception where the API call expects nothing more than an unnamed list of strings, something like:

```
["abc", "def", "ghi", ...]
```

In order to maintain consistency around validating input I'd like to keep using marhmallow, even for this simple case. I thought that a simple schema like this would work:

```
class MySimpleSchema(Schema):
    fields.List(fields.Str(default=''))
```

However when running the following code I end up with the error below:

```
my_schema = MySimpleSchema()
my_simple_list = ["item1","item1","item1"]
data = my_schema.load(my_simple_list)
```

> validation error: {'_schema': ['Invalid input type.']}

Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When loading, i.e., deserializing objects, Marshmallow's `load` method [expects a dictionary](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html?highlight=load#deserializing-objects-loading) (or a string containing a dictionary, in the case of [`loads`](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_reference.html#marshmallow.Schema.loads)).

So a couple of changes need to be made:

1. In the definition of the schema, there's no other way but to define the field as an attribute:

```
class MySimpleSchema(Schema):
    field1 = fields.List(fields.Str(default=''))
```

2. Call `load` with a dictionary, e.g.:

```
my_schema = MySimpleSchema()
data = {"field1": ["item1", "item2", "item3"]}
data = my_schema.load(data)
```

In your case, if you really want to use Marshmallow for validation, you could first wrap the unnamed list of strings within a dictionary (note that the key has to match the field defined in the schema). So something like this would work:

```
my_schema = MySimpleSchema()
my_simple_list = ["item1","item1","item1"]
data = my_schema.load({"field1": my_simple_list})
```

Added to that, if you just want to validate input data without deserializing it, you can use `Schema.validate()`:

```
my_simple_list = [1,"item1","item1"]
errors = my_schema.validate({"field1": my_simple_list})
print(errors)
```

Output:

```
marshmallow.exceptions.ValidationError: {'field1': {0: ['Not a valid string.']}}
```